# transforming global index of a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays

We can consider an array A with 256 values. Each value is an array of 256 values. Then index is from 0 to 65535 ( 256*256 ).
getting : A[x][y] => the goal is to transform index to x and y

0 <= x <= 255 & 0 <= y <= 255

What are the two transformations ?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in c++, `/` is **integer division**, and `%` is **remainder**

```
x = Global_index % 256, y = (Global_index/256) % 256
```